# How to connect an alexa skill with an existing mongodb atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am pretty new to Alexa skills. I made a 'hello world' skill and got some HTTP requests going.

Now I am trying to connect my skill to an existing MongoDB atlas cluster. My goal is to retrieve some data from my cluster and use it in my skill to respond to the user who asked Alexa something.

I think I established a connection to atlas but when I try to do something with my collection from the DB I am getting a 'MongoError: Topology was destroyed' Error.

As I already read the problem could be in the workflow from AWS Lambda. It's working stateless and the connection could already be broken when I try to read the collection but I don't know how I should solve this problem.

This is my current approach to establish a connection and just print the count of my documents. I tested to move the client connect part around in my skill but I always get the same error.

## The current approach to establishing a connection

---

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASS>@<CLUSTER>?retryWrites=true";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("database").collection("data");
    console.log(collection.countDocuments());
    client.close();
});
```

## This is how one Intent of my skills looks like:

---

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Hello World!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
}};
```

## This is how the actual error looks like:

---

```
    Promise {
    <rejected> { MongoError: Topology was destroyed
    at initializeCursor (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb- 
   core/lib/cursor.js:603:25)
    at nextFunction (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:463:12)
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor.next (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:763:3)
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor._next (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:211:36)
    at fetchDocs (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:217:12)
    at toArray (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:247:3)
    at executeOperation (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
    at AggregationCursor.Cursor.toArray (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:824:10)
    at countDocuments (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:233:37)
    at /var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:437:24 name: 'MongoError', [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on my other AWS lambda function which used to connect MongoDb and I found that we need to provide additional parameters in connection to Mongodb as mentioned below.

`var options = {
  server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } },
  replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }
};
mongoose.connect(secrets.db, options);`

Please try and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried a similar solution. It does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'use strict'

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let cachedDb = null;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

function connectToDatabase(uri) {

    if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
        console.log('=> using cached database instance');
        return Promise.resolve(cachedDb);
    }
    const dbName = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';
    return MongoClient.connect(uri)
        .then(client => { cachedDb = client.db(dbName); return cachedDb; });
}
```

try this way